# Altium Designer: How to handle these type of Nets?

Tags: schematics, altium, error

I have such complicated Bus [0..4], which go out from Page 2 to Page 1, and then from Page 1 to Page 3 as shown in the figure below which is a Top Sheet:

[image]

I receive the following error when I compile the project:

*Net (xxx) contains multiple output sheet entrys*

I still receive the same error even if I change port names and/or net names..

How to solve it ?!

Comment: You have two ports with the same name on Page 1. You also have the same bus names. Change port names on Page 1 to something unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the signals on the bus from Page 2 to Page 1 are same like signals from Page 1 to Page 3 (they should be if you named buses with same name), then you can connect Page 3 directly with Page 2. You don't need two ports on Page 1. If they are not same, then you should change name of the buses and ports on Page 1.
You also need to set hierarchical structure of your project if you are are planing to use Top sheet.